# Change CSS of specific row on click instead of the button

Tags: jquery, css, dom, html-table

So I have this button, you click it and it changes the `background color` from blue to red. If I wanted to have that button change the `row background color` instead, how would I do that? This is in a loop too so all the classes are the same, I use the below code so it only changes whatever I clicked instead of everything with that class.

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.a-row').on('click', '.H', function () {
    $( this ).css( "background-color", "red" );
});
</script>
```

**html/php**

```
<tr class="a-row">
 <td><p class="pname"><?=$row["Name"]?></p><p class="clickbutt H">H</p></td>
 <td>stuff</td>
 <td>stuff2</td>
 <td>stuff3</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.parents()` method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.a-row').on('click', '.H', function () {
    $( this ).parents("tr").css( "background-color", "red" );
});
</script>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2ustn4zu/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.closest('tr')`:

```
$('.a-row').on('click', '.H', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

[jquery .closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the .closest() method of jquery like so.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.H').on('click', function () {
  $( this ).closest.('tr').css( "background-color", "red" );
 });
</script>
```

You can check out the documemtation here. https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Hope this wasa helpful.